# Why we have to clear the ax register when we are going to use a user input?

Tags: assembly, keyboard, x86, dos, xor

Well my question is that, why we have to clear with `xor ax,ax` the `ax` register?  I thought that  when the user inputs a character for variable `A`, and when users input again a character for variable `B`, this could overwrite the content value in `ax`, but it seems to be different.

This is in x86 assembly.

Using DOS, an ASSEMBLER FOR 16 bits.
Pressing any character with the DOS interruptions:

```
mov ah, 01h
```

Comment: what 'character input' are we talking here? direct reading from keyboard data buffer? OS API?

Comment: This does not make any sense without more context. What OS? How do read keyboard? Do you use OS API (which API call?), BIOS call (which one?) or a custom keyboard handler or something else?

Comment: So sorry, I am talking about DOS, a 16 BITS ASSEMBLER, Any character from the keyboard. Using the DOS INTERRUPTIONS: mov ah, 01h

Answer (score 3):

Because in AH you are sending a parameter for INT 16,

if AH == 0 then read keyboard input

if AH == 1 then query keyboard status/preview key
etc..

Read [this](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0228.HTM).

Comment: To complement on ladan's answer, "xor" was (is?) frequently used because it saved a few clock cycles compared to something more readable as "mov ax, 0".

Comment: @Luis In 16-bit x86 code `xor ax,ax` is encoded as `31 C0` (2 bytes), whereas `mov ax,0` is encoded as `B8 00 00` (3 bytes). So you save one byte by using `xor ax,ax`. In 808x [`xor`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/xor.html)`ax,ax`  was 1 clock faster than [`mov`](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/mov.html)`ax,0` (3 clocks < 4 clocks), in 286...486 the clocks were identical, and since Pentium things got a lot more complicated and instruction execution times could not be expressed anymore as a number of clocks.

Comment: @nrz I agree, optimizations and rules of thumb of yore don't necessarily apply anymore. Most optimizations are better left to compilers unless you know exactly what you're doing and what hardware you're working on.